# How to have a text file created based on user input C++

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++. I'm creating a code that will input a file and output the results in an output file, and using stacks and junk.

But what i want to do is create a file based on a user input. Asking the user (when a file doesn't exist in a specific directory) if they would like to create that empty file. I've done this on C# using Directory and Dictionary, but C++ isn't really clicking for me. Here's the snippet of my code (I'm not going to paste 200+ lines for one thing) and where i want to do. Ignore the comments. It's just to keep track of what I'm doing.

```
if (file.is_open()) //if the file is open (and works)
{
string output;
cout << "Please enter the full directory of  the file you would like to have the results in" << endl;
cin >> output;
output.c_str();
file_result.open(output); //open the results file for checking answers 
while (file_result.fail())
{
cout << "This file does not exist. Would you like to make one?" << endl;
}
```

As you see, where I ask the user if they would like to make that file is where i would want this to be.

Any help would be lovely! Transitioning from C# to C++ was a bad idea.

Comment: ostream creates the file automatically if it doesn't exist. So writing to a file even if the user didn't want to doesn't make sense

Comment: As you just answered, I saw that on a library reference on cpluscplus.com

And you have no idea how ashamed I am right now.

Comment: Why `while (file_result.fail())` ? You want just an `if` as far as I understand. Then you need to read user input, probably something like `char answer; cin >> answer;` and take action depending on it. But that's assuming you reach this code, as you didn't even describe what your issue is (i.e what is the current result you obtain).

Comment: My intention was to double check the user. If what they typed in didn't exist, it would just be made. So what I get right now is a file that the computer thinks is made.

But yeah I literally just did an ostream, and everything worked as i intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way to create a file based off of user input is this, You should how ever include checks to make sure the path is valid and that no file exists etc.. I only have time to show you how to do this.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{  
  ofstream outFile;
  string path;
  cout << "Please enter the full path for your file: ";
  getline(cin, path);
  outFile.open(path);

  return 0;
}
```

What's happening here is quite simple the user inputs the full path (C:\Hello.txt) it's read by getline(cin, path) and is stored in path.

outfile then creates that file.

Please make sure you add checks to validate no file with that name already exists etc.. I'll update this later with a better example but this will create a file for you

Answer (score 2):

You can open a file for writting (in append mode) in this way:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open (output.c_str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
ofs << " more lorem ipsum";
ofs.close();
```

More information about file operations can be found here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

Comment: Thanks! Using ofstream did what I wanted!